# php dynamical html titles

Tags: php, html, seo, title

I would like to have one php file which will be included in head of every web page in my web and it will echo title and meta description for that page. Php will check what is the current page URL and depending on that will echo title and meta description. My question is: will crawlers be able do read titles normally and will this type of rendering titles and descriptions be bad for SEO (I don't see how can CMS for SEO be built in another way)?

Here is my code of php file for echoing titles:

```
<?php 


    $myurl = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

    if (strpos($myurl, '?') !== false) 
    {
        $myurl = substr($myurl, 0, strpos($myurl, '?'));
    }


    if ($myurl == "/index.php")
        echo '<title>My index title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">';
    else if ($myurl == "/services.php")
        echo '<title>My service title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">';

?>
```

Comment: Web crawlers and SEO can't see your PHP code.  As long as the resulting page is constructed the way you expect it to be, no external system can know how your server-side code actually arrived at that resulting page.

Answer (score 0):

The crawlers will be able to read the pages normally. As long as the page files that reference it are different it will be fine.